# What are the disadvantages of using ORC file format?

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

I've read many posts about how great the ORC file format is for compression and fast querying, notably as compared to the Parquet format.
I understand how ORC splits the data across row groups, subdivides them into groups of columns, and how it uses metadata and internal statistics to skip through whole blocks of data. I understand how it's particularly great for Hive, in query speedup and if you need Hive ACID transactions.

**Are there any obvious DISADVANTAGES in using ORC?**

I'd like a concise view of when you'd absolutely would NOT want to use ORC. So far I've found a few vague hints about it 'not working well with Spark', and it being 'less efficient with nested data', I'd like to better understand why this would be so.

Apologies if this turns out to be a duplicate, I'm yet to find a question with a thorough answer on this.

Answer (score 0):

One scenario that we came across that made us jump to parquet was that before Spark 2.3, there were no vectorized readers for ORC. They are working on feature parity between parquet and ORC in spark and Spark 2.3 really goes a long way in accomplishing this.

We did a benchmark on a reasonable large table and a window function to compute something complex and parquet beat orc with spark 2.1 hands down. On wide tables(500+ columns) this became super evident. But when it came to Spark 2.3, we had virtually identical performance. Also to be noted, spark 2.3 comes with a newer version of orc as well, so using this and reading a legacy table with the new spark also had performance differences between each other.

You can read more about this on their JIRA board [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-20901).